# Splitting Perl string and adding _ in between

Tags: perl

Question. I am trying to read in perl string from command line e.g. "abcdef" and then split this into "a_b_c_d_e_f".

I am struggling with logic part. any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while($line=<STDIN>){
  chomp $line;
  split $line;

join ("_", $line);

print $line;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"logic part"*. The only logical statement in that code is `while`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `split` manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) actually includes exactly this example:

```
print join(':', split('', 'abc')), "\n";
```

Adjusting to use `_` instead of `:` and `$line` instead of `'abc'`, we get:

```
print join('_', split('', $line)), "\n";
```

The most important point is that `split` doesn't modify its arguments, it just returns a list, and `join` doesn't modify its arguments, it just returns a string. So it never makes sense to call `split` or `join` without using the return-value.

Comment: The first parameter to `split` is a *regex* and shouldn't be specified as a string

Comment: @Borodin: Yeah, that's strange. I always specify it as a regex, personally; not sure why the man-page does this one differently.

Comment: I agree. I think that's a documentation bug.

Comment: @Borodin There are two special cases where `split` does not treat its first argument as a regex: the empty string `''` and a single literal space `' '`. `split ''` and `split //` both match on empty strings; this is contrary to the behavior of `m//`, which uses the last successfully matched regex. I agree that this behavior is somewhat counter intuitive but it's certainly documented.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
print join('_', split //, $line), "\n";
```

Comment: I think you're `split //,` should be `split('',`.

Comment: @Drewness: ***No***, absolutely not. The first parameter to `split` is a *regular expression* except in the special case where you can pass a single literal space, which is equivalent to requesting the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
print join('_', split('', $line)), '\n';
```

You can read more about perl's `split()` function [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you *must* use `split`, you can use a between-character substitution for this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'abcdef';
$string =~ s/(?<=.)(?:)(?=.)/_/g;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
a_b_c_d_e_f
```

Hope this helps!